# DRF-How to save foreign keys data using APIView

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys

everyone, I am absolutely a beginner in DjangoRestFramework. I have confusion to deal with relationships in DRF. How do I save foreign keys data using APIView?

## models

```
   class User(AbstractUser):
        email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
        is_client = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        is_professional = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        
    
    class Client(models.Model):
            user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='client')
            ##
        
    class Professionals(models.Model):
            user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='professional')
            ##


    class HireProfessional(models.Model):
        client = models.ForeignKey(Client, related_name='user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        professional = models.ForeignKey(Professionals, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="professsional")
        hire_start_date_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

## Serializers

```
    class ProfessionalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        profilePicture = serializers.ImageField(allow_empty_file=True, use_url='professional/profiles', required=False)
        skill = SkillSerializer(many=True,read_only=True)
        class Meta:
            model = Professionals
            fields = fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'profilePicture', 'profession', 'phone_number', 'experience', 'skill', 'charge_fee', 'about_me']


    class ClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Client
            fields = ['user_id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'phone_number', 'profilePicture']

    class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        client = ClientSerializer()
        professional = ProfessionalSerializer()
        class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'username', 'is_client', 'is_professional', 'client', 'professional')

    




    class HireProfessionalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        client = ClientSerializer()
        professional = professionalSerializer()

        class Meta:
        model = HireProfessional
        fields = ['id','client', 'professional', 'hire_start_date_time']
```

## views ##Edited

```
    
class HireProfessionalCreateApp(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsClientUser,)

    def current_user(self):
        user = self.request.user.client
        return user


    

    def post(self, request, username, format=None):
        try:
            professional = Professionals.objects.get(user__username=username)
            # print('hello', professional.user_id)
            data = request.data
            
            data['client'] = self.current_user()
            data['professional'] = professional.user_id

            serializer = HireProfessionalSerializer(data=data)
            data = {}
            if serializer.is_valid():
                hire = serializer.save()
                hire.save()
                                    
                return JsonResponse ({
                    "message":"professional hired success.",
                    # "remaning_time":remaning_datetime,
                    "success" : True,
                    "result" : serializer.data,
                    "status" : status.HTTP_201_CREATED
                })
            else:
                data = serializer.errors
                print(data)


            return Response(serializer.data)
         except Professionals.DoesNotExist:
            return JsonResponse ({"status":status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, 'message':'professional does not exists'})
```

This is a hiring app.

Client able to hire to professional

client=logged in user

professional=passed id or username through URL

like: `path('hire-professional/<professional id or username>', views)`

Does anybody have any idea? how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a [`ModelViewSet`](https://www.cdrf.co/3.12/rest_framework.viewsets/ModelViewSet.html) instead of an `APIView` since you're directly modifying the `HireProfessional` model. Additionally, the model uses `ForeignKey` fields for `Client` and `Professional`, you do **not** need to include their respective serializers in `HireProfessionalSerializer`.

Implementing just the `ModelViewSet` (and adding it to the `urls.py` using a [router](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#defaultrouter)) will mean that a user can select the client & professional themself, which means we're not done yet. It is recommended to use a `router` in DRF instead of adding all the views to `urls.py` manually.

You can use the ModelViewSet to override the [`perform_create`](https://www.cdrf.co/3.12/rest_framework.viewsets/ModelViewSet.html#perform_create) and [`perform_update`](https://www.cdrf.co/3.12/rest_framework.viewsets/ModelViewSet.html#perform_update) functions in which you autofill serializer fields. :

default create function

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
       serializer.save()
```

autofill example

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
        # client is derived from logged in user
        client = Client.objects.get(user=self.request.user)

        # Autofill FK Client.
        serializer.save(client=client)
```

Now the client is autofilled, but the professional isn't yet. If you want to also autofill the professional you will have to look into using a [nested router](https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers) since you want to retrieve the PK(id) from the URL. If you do so your URL would look something like this:

```
url='/professionals/{professionals_pk}/hire/'
```

I hope this gives you an idea of where to start. If you have any questions do let me know.